# Is there a way to ask if part of a domain is included in document.referrer?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, referrer, allow-modals

I'm setting up a modal for our website, and we want it to only appear if a user is coming into any of our pages from an external page (i.e. from google to our page). The modal should show up on all pages, so I have it set up in our header since that's one of two sections that is constant throughout our site (the other being the footer). I have a modal coming in for certain pages using a document.referrer conditional, but the code is set up that I would have to literally type out every single other url in our website (over 500 pages) in order for that to work.

So the question is, is there a way I can target the domain URL in a conditional, where **if the domain is included in the previous page (referrer) url, then don't show the modal**?

Here is the example of the modal I have now:

```
const domains = ["http://website.com/*"];

            if (domains.includes(document.referrer)) {
              console.log("Don't Show Modal - from any park page", document.referrer);
            } else {
              console.log("Show Modal - From other Page", document.referrer);

              $( window ).on('load', function() {
                 console.log("closure modal firing");
                 $('#closureModal').modal({
                 backdrop: 'static',
                 keyboard: false,
                 show: true
                 });
              });

            }
```

`#closureModal` is connected to the modal HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the [`URL` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to perform this comparison. You'll have to use hostnames in your `domains` array (i.e., no protocol or path) or process the entries in `domains` through `URL` as well, but either way it should be pretty robust for what you need it to do.

```js
const domains = ["stackoverflow.com"];
const referrer_hostname = new URL(document.referrer).hostname;

if (domains.includes(referrer_hostname)) {
  console.log("Don't Show Modal - from any park page", document.referrer);
} else {
  console.log("Show Modal - From other Page", document.referrer);
  /* modal manipulation */
}
```

Comment: It turns out this isn't working as I'd hoped - when a user types in our URL, the modal doesn't show. the modal only shows if they click on our URL from another site (i.e. Google search). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I would recommend brushing up on some of the more basic constructs around [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer). From the linked page: "*The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark).*" If the user reached the page through directly entering the URL, you'd have to account for that in your conditional statement.